# FBConnect's handleOpenURL Method Not Called by my AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, fbconnect

I have implemented the FBConnect SDK into my app, and it works perfectly on the simulator.  I then modified my app's .plist file appropriately, and added the necessary method to my AppDelegate for when Facebook is installed on the device:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
NSLog(@"handleOpenURL Method was called and sent the following:");
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url];     
NSLog(@"URL String: %@", urlString);
return [[flipsideViewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

From the above NSLogs and the observation that my application is returned to the foreground after authorizing access via Facebook, I infer that the FB App is handing off control to my application appropriately.  Unfortunately, Facebook.m's "handleOpenURL:url" method does not actually get called as I request in my AppDelegate (i.e. neither of the below NSLogs are displayed).

```
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
// If the URL's structure doesn't match the structure used for Facebook authorization, abort.
NSLog(@"handleOpenURL was handled by SDK. Good!");
if (![[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:[self getOwnBaseUrl]]) {
NSLog(@"handleOpenURL structure doesn't match the structure used for Facebook authorization. Aborting.");
return NO;
}
//...
```

As a result, my app's view controller (where I clicked my facebook button to begin with) is simply returned to the screen, and the code I placed in the 'fbDidLogin' method (used in my view controller to publish to the user's wall) never gets called as it did in the simulator.

**What am I overlooking?  What, if any, other information is needed to solve this problem?  Any help would be very much appreciated, as I have been struggling with this for a while.**

Important Summary Notes: 
1.) Application runs as desired on simulator.
2.) handleOpenURL Method not called when I request it from my AppDelegate.
3.) I do not receive any errors/warnings.
4.) I can run the DemoApp on my device, and I notice that the handleOpenURL Method is called appropiately when requested by the 'DemoAppAppDelegate.'

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What version of iOS are you running on the device?

Comment: @Rayfleck Version 4.3.3 on device and 4.3 on Simulator. This question came about after asking the question of [why I was seeing different results on my device in the first place->LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190211/connecting-publishing-to-facebook-with-fbconnect-works-on-simulator-but-not-ipho)

Comment: I found the solution here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783782/fbdidlogin-not-called-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783782/fbdidlogin-not-called-ios) open the facebook.m file and find the following line: [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES]; and change it to [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up having to make my facebook object a singleton (stored in the appDelegate).  Not completely sure why this was necessary though, as I was not using the fb object in multiple viewControllers.  Please comment if you know why this was necessary.

See the following links for more information:

[handleOpenUrl and TabBar Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998384/facebook-ios-handleopenurl-tabbar-application)

[Facebook SDK: Call from multiple viewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340375/facebook-ios-sdk-iphone-call-from-multiple-viewcontroller)

[Cocoa with Love: Singletons](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)